# Rbind throwing Error in NextMethod() : invalid value

Tags: r, rbind

My data frame is as follows:

```
> t
     Day TestID VarID
1 2013-04-27  Total Total

> str(t)
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Day   : Date, format: "2013-04-27"
 $ TestID: factor [1, 1] Total
  ..- attr(*, "levels")= chr "Total"
 $ VarID : Factor w/ 3 levels "0|0","731|18503",..: 3
```

When I try doing a rbind I get the following error

```
> rbind(t,t)
Error in NextMethod() : invalid value
```

but when I try to recreate the data frame directly I don't get that error:

```
> t <- data.frame(Day = as.Date("2013-04-27"),TestID = "Total", VarID = "Total")
> t
     Day TestID VarID
1 2013-04-27  Total Total
> str(t)
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Day   : Date, format: "2013-04-27"
 $ TestID: Factor w/ 1 level "Total": 1
 $ VarID : Factor w/ 1 level "Total": 1
> rbind(t,t)
     Day TestID VarID
1 2013-04-27  Total Total
2 2013-04-27  Total Total
```

Can anyone help me figure out what is going on and how can I avoid this error.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide the output of `dput()` on the version of the data frame for which `rbind` does not work?

Comment: Thanks for suggesting dput. I will use that in the future. For now this issue is resolved. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The major difference I see is that the `TestID` variable in the first version is `factor [1, 1]` (a matrix) rather than `Factor` (a vector)

First version:

```
t1 <- data.frame(Day = as.Date("2013-04-27"),
                 TestID = "Total", VarID = "Total")
rbind(t1,t1)
```

Convert to second version:

```
t2 <- t1
dim(t2$TestID) <- c(1,1)
str(t2$TestID)
##  factor [1, 1] Total
##  - attr(*, "levels")= chr "Total"
rbind(t2,t2)
## Error in NextMethod() : invalid value
```

Fix the mangled version:

```
t3 <- t2
t3$TestID <- drop(t3$TestID)
rbind(t3,t3)  ## works
```

Comment: Thanks, This fixed the issue. I am now applying drop on both the data frames before rbind. Still not clear what was going on?

Comment: We would have to know much more about how the data frame was constructed in the first place to answer that ... in general data frames don't contain matrices, but they can be constructed using `I()` (from `?data.frame`: If a list or data frame or matrix is passed to ‘data.frame’ it is as if each component or column had been passed as a separate argument (except for matrices of class ‘"model.matrix"’ and those protected by ‘I’), or by setting the `class` of a list to `data.frame` manually ...